How to forward OpenAI's stream response using FastAPI in python?
This is my code to retrieve stream response from OpenAI's model which is event based. (I have shown only core part)
client = OpenAI(api_key=OPEN_AI_API_KEY)

class EventHandler(AssistantEventHandler):
    def on_text_delta(self, delta: TextDelta, snapshot: Text):
        print(delta.value)

with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
    thread_id=thread_id,
    assistant_id=assistant_id,
    event_handler=EventHandler()
) as stream:
stream.until_done()

on_text_delta event triggers as tokens arrives from API. I want to forward this response using FastAPI instead of printing on output screen.
@app.get("/stream")
async def stream():
    return ...something...

I have tried responding result as part of HTTP body:
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

...

@app.post("/stream")
async def stream():
    with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
        thread_id=thread_id,
        assistant_id=assistant_id,
        event_handler=EventHandler()
    ) as stream:
        stream.until_done()

    return StreamingResponse(EventHandler.generator_function(), media_type="text/plain")

I have created generator_function inside EventHandler class but problem is until stream is not over the execution doesn't reach return statement.
I have also tried websockets, but still problem is how should my program execution should flow. The stream doesn't let execution go further until API response is completed.

The issue in your question is due to the asynchronous nature of the request/response behaviour. You need to structure the stream in a non blocking way.

Does this answer your question?

This answer might prove helpful as well.

@Chris The first uses openai.ChatCompletion which is iterable which enables to use of a Python generator for StreamingResponse and the second one is not related to my question.

I found the solution!
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from openai import OpenAI, AsyncOpenAI


OPEN_AI_API_KEY = 'you_api_key'
async_client = AsyncOpenAI(api_key=OPEN_AI_API_KEY)
client = OpenAI(api_key=OPEN_AI_API_KEY)

app = FastAPI()

async def stream_assistant_response(assistant_id, thread_id):
    stream =  async_client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
        assistant_id=assistant_id,
        thread_id=thread_id
    )

    async with stream as stream:
        async for text in stream.text_deltas:
            yield f"data: {text}\n\n"


@app.get("/message")
async def add_message(assistant_id, thread_id, message):
    # make sure thread exist
    client.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread_id=thread_id,
        role="user",
        content=message
    )

    return StreamingResponse(stream_assistant_response(assistant_id, thread_id), media_type="text/event-stream")


from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from openai import OpenAI
from openai import TextDelta

# Initialize FastAPI and OpenAI client
app = FastAPI()
client = OpenAI(api_key="YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY")  # Replace with your OpenAI API key

class EventHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response_data = []

    async def on_text_delta(self, delta: TextDelta, snapshot: str):
        # Append the delta value to response_data
        self.response_data.append(delta.value)

    async def generator_function(self):
        for data in self.response_data:
            yield data

@app.post("/stream")
async def stream(thread_id: str, assistant_id: str):
    handler = EventHandler()

    async def stream_response():
        # Start streaming from OpenAI
        with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
            thread_id=thread_id,
            assistant_id=assistant_id,
            event_handler=handler
        ) as stream:
            # Wait until the stream is done
            stream.until_done()
            # Yield each response data piece
            for data in handler.response_data:
                yield data

    return StreamingResponse(stream_response(), media_type="text/plain")

# Optional: Test client to fetch the stream
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    import httpx
    import asyncio

    async def fetch_stream():
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            async with client.post("http://localhost:8000/stream", json={"thread_id": "your_thread_id", "assistant_id": "your_assistant_id"}) as response:
                async for line in response.aiter_text():
                    print(line)

    # Run the FastAPI server
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

    # Uncomment the line below to test the stream
    # asyncio.run(fetch_stream())


stream.until_done() method doesn't let the execution go further so StreamingResponse would be possible only at the end when the whole answer is generated.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
